# Password is not matching while logging in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this code while registering the form:

```
function register()
    {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[txt_password]|md5');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');  
//other codes


$data = array('username' => $this->input->post('txt_username'),
              'password' => $this->input->post('txt_password')
            );

            // insert form data into database
           if ($this->account_model->insertUser($data));
             { 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','successfully registered!');
            redirect('account/register');
        }
}
```

the password matches here.
but when i use same data to username and password to login: it displays invalid username or password:
the login function is as follows:

```
function login()
{
                    //set validations
          $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_username", "Username", "trim|required");
          $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_password", "Password", "trim|required");

              $username = $this->input->post("txt_username");
              $password = $this->input->post("txt_password");

                $usr_result = $this->account_model->get_user($username, $password);

                    if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                    {
                    $this->account_model->login();
            $data['message'] ="You are logged in!"; 
        }
                    else
                    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Invalid username and password!');
                    }
        }
}
```

I have this model for inserting registration form data to database:

```
function insertUser($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    }
```

and i have this model to retreive data to login:

```
function get_user($usr, $pwd)
     {
          $sql = "select * from user where username = '" . $usr . "' and password = '".md5($pwd). "'";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          return $query->num_rows();
     }
```

Comment: `md5()` is not a secure encryption/hash method anymore. You aren't sanitizing any user input, leaving yourself open to major [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.

Comment: Security is not a big deal for my purpose and i have edited the question with inputs.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal you may use SHA512 for encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method [instead of `MD5`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713988/password-is-not-matching-while-logging-in#comment57174262_34713988) is use `base64` in Codeigniter. That means  [`decode()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html?highlight=decode#CI_Encrypt::decode) and [`encode()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html?highlight=decode#CI_Encrypt::encode).

---

**Encoding**

```
$password = 'mYp@ssw0rd'; // or $password
$encriptKey = 'super-secret-key';

$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($password, $encriptKey);
```

**Decoding**

```
$password = 'mYp@ssw0rd'; // or $password
$encriptKey = 'super-secret-key';

$decrypted_string = $this->encrypt->decode($password, $encriptKey);
```

**In Addition**

Load library  as well `$this->load->library('encrypt');`

Comment: No. sorry. Just an accidental click. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please store encrypted password at insert time.
**for example:**

```
$data['password'] = md5($data['password']);
```

I think it will resolve your problem.
Other code is working fine for me.

Comment: the inserted password is encrypted as i can see it in the database.

Comment: md5 is not secure any more would not use for password. this is better for hasing http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: i have used ` $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('txt_username'),
   'password'=>md5($this->input->post('txt_password')),   
   
);` still doesnot work @Nihar

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your model:

```
public function login()
    {
        $user = $this->get_by(array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),

            'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),

        ), TRUE);



        if (count($user)) 
        {
            // Log in user
            $data = array(
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'id' => $user->id,
                'user_type'=>$user->user_type,
                'emp_id'=>$user->emp_id,
                'loggedin' => TRUE,
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return TRUE; 
        }
        return FALSE;
    }


    public function logout ()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in','id','name','email');

    }

    public function loggedin ()
    {
        return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
    }



    public function hash ($string)
    {
        return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
    }
```

And can let a user login. Use CI Session for login which would be a better option.
Read More [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

For Controller Do this:

```
public function login()
{

    $dashboard ='admin/dashboard';




    $rules = $this->secure_m->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {

        if ($this->secure_m->login() == TRUE)
        {

                $this->secure_m->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);
                redirect($dashboard);

        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'That email/password combination does not exist');
            redirect('secure/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    $this->load->view("Your View");

}
```